# Is there a 'simple' way to dynamically render views in vue?

Tags: vue.js

Let's take a step back and look at the use case:

You're defining a modular interface, and any module that implements it must be able to 'render itself' into the application given a slot and a state.

How do you do it in vue?

##### Example solution

Let's have a look at the most basic implementation I can assemble:

(full example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8zclnp?file=src/App.vue)

We have a layout:

```
# Layout.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <hr />
    <slot name="moduleView" />
    <hr />
  </div>
</template>
```

...and an app with a module:

```
# App.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import type { MyModuleState } from "./MyModule";
import Layout from "./Layout.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { MyModule } from "./MyModule";
import ModView from "./ModView.vue";

const state = ref<MyModuleState>({ value: 0 });
const module = new MyModule();

const onClick = () => {
  state.value = { value: state.value.value + 1 };
};

const renderModule = () => {
  return module.view(state.value);
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>currentValue: {{ state.value }}</div>
  <div>update: <button @click="onClick">++</button></div>
  <div>
    <Layout>
      <template v-slot:moduleView>
        <mod-view :render="renderModule" :state="state" />  // <--- But this!
      </template>
    </Layout>
  </div>
</template>
```

...but rendering into the slot requires a lot of jumping through obscure hoops:

```
# ModView.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import ModRender from "./ModRender";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import type { VNode } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  render: (state?: any) => VNode | Array<VNode>;
  state?: any;
}>();

const nodes = ref(props.render(props.state));

watch( // <-- Obscure! The view won't update unless you explicitly watch props?
  () => props.state,
  (nextState) => {
    nodes.value = props.render(nextState);
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <mod-render :nodes="nodes" />
</template>
```

```
# ModRender.ts
import type { VNode } from "vue";

const ModRender = (props: { nodes: VNode | Array<VNode> }) => {
  return props.nodes;
};

ModRender.props = {
  nodes: {
    required: true,
  },
};

export default ModRender; // <--- Super obscure, why do you need a functional component for this?
```

Before we can define the actual module:

```
# MyModule.ts
import type { VNode } from "vue";
import { h } from "vue";
import ModuleView from "./MyModuleDisplay.vue";

interface AbstractModule<T> {
  view: (state: T) => VNode;
}

export interface MyModuleState {
  value: number;
}

export class MyModule implements AbstractModule<MyModuleState> {
  view(state: MyModuleState): VNode {
    return h(ModuleView, { state });
  }
}
```

...and a component for it:

```
# MyModuleView.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { MyModuleState } from "./MyModule";
const props = defineProps<{ state: MyModuleState }>();
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ state.value }}</div>
</template>
```

##### What.

This seems extremely obtuse and verbose.

Am I missing something?

In other component systems an implementation might look like:

```
export class MyModule implements AbstractModule<MyModuleState> {
  view(state: MyModuleState): VNode {
    return (<div>{state.value}</div>);
  }
}

...

<div>
  <Layout>{renderModule(state)}</Layout>
</div>
```

It seems surprising that so many wrappers and hoops have to be done in vue to do this, which makes me feel like I'm missing something.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Vnode objects cannot be rendered in component templates as is and need to be wrapped in a component like `ModRender`. If they are used as universal way to exchange template data in the app, that's a problem. Vnodes still can be directly used in component render functions and functional components with JSX or `h` like `<Layout>{renderModule(state)}</Layout>`, this limits their usage.

`AbstractModule` convention may need to be reconsidered if it results in unnecessary code. Proceed from the fact that a "view" needs to be used with dynamic `<component>` at some point, and it will be as straightforward as possible.

There may be no necessity for "module" abstraction, but even if there is, `module.view`  can return a component (functional or stateful) instead of vnodes. Or it can construct a component and make it available as a property, e.g.:

```
class MyModule {
  constructor(state) {
    this.viewComponent = (props) => h(ModuleView, { state, ...props })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; in your example, the signature of viewComponent is `(props) => VNode`; how is that different from the `view: (state: T) => VNode;` in my example?

Comment: The difference is that it should be not random function but functional component, i.e. a function with specific signature. It has 1 parameter, which is props read-only object, not state object. If you don't pass `state` from a place where this component is used, it won't get it.